# Using if, and, or to compare field values and assign new value in Python Parser of ArcMap Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.4

I have 3 fields in a table that i need to evaluate and return a new value based on the results using the field calculator (PYTHON)

They are:
SETSPAID (long)  This field must = 0
TYPEOFSERVICE (string)  This field must = 1 or 3
STATUS (double) This field can not be 5 or 6

Here is what I have so far:

Pre-logic Script Code:

```py
def calc(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8):

  if f4 == f5 and (f1 == f2 or f1 == f3) and (f6 != f7 or f6 != f8):
    return 1
  else:
    return f4
```

SETSPD =

```py
calc(!TYPEOFSERVICE!, '1', '3', !SETSPAID!, 0, !STATUS!, 5, 6)
```

When I run this code, it still assigns a 1 when status is 6.
Not sure what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `if` line you need to change your `or` to an `and` in the last part.

```
if f4 == f5 and (f1 == f2 or f1 == f3) and (f6 != f7 and f6 != f8):
```

This is because with `f6 != f7` (`6 != 5`) it returns 1, even though `f6 != f8` fails (`6 = 6`) in the second part.  With the `OR` there it returns true if one of them is true.  With an `AND` it would return true only if both are true.